# OffsetDateTime.parse('2018-12-03T18:07:55') throwing DateTimeParseException

Tags: java-time

I believe this should work. Granted it has no specified offset, but shouldn't that then default to UTC? And if not, how can I parse a string like this into an OffsetDateTime?

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd['T'[HH:mm:ss][.SSSSS]][z][x]");
String datetime = "2018-12-03T18:07:55";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(datetime, formatter);
```

Exception thrown:
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-12-03T18:07:55' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2018-12-03T18:07:55 of type java.time.format.Parsed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, it's failing because there's no offset in the format. To work around this, you can use the same format to parse to a `LocalDateTime`, and then combine with a `ZoneOffset` to create an `OffsetDateTime`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd['T'[HH:mm:ss][.SSSSS]][z][x]");
String datetime = "2018-12-03T18:07:55";

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(datetime, formatter);
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneOffset.UTC);

System.out.println(odt);
```